# How to prevent songs from getting uploaded with iTunes match?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

Is there a way to manually exclude songs from getting uploaded to iTunes match?

Comment: Why would you want to exclude certain songs?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is important to answer the question, however: because this are unreleased recordings from myself and some of my bands which I don't want to be anywhere else than on my local machine and my local backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(take a copy of your songs)** delete the songs you don't want on match, re-add them but change the *type* (right klick, info) to *audio-book* hence *iCloud don't upload audiobooks*

[image]

To be clear - the AudioBooks that are incorrectly marked 'music' cannot have their identifier edited (when already uploaded to cloud), as the Get Info> Options> Media Kind is greyed out. You must save the audio away from iTunes, and when you reload it, you can change the option before it's uploaded.